# Launch another jar at runtime but make the originally launched jar available for deletion

Tags: java, jar, classloader

My scenario is:

I want to have my Main Application. It's main is being run in the usual way, `java -jar MainApplication.jar`.

That application should be able to run another jar file on the file system (e.g. `UpdaterApplication.jar`) that would then delete the `MainApplication.jar` and replaced it with a updated new one.

Injecting the `UpdaterApplication.jar` into the classpath and then using reflection does not work, because the `MainApplication.jar` is obviously still loaded.

How could I invoke the second jar and make the first one free for deletion after the second jar has been started?

It would be fine if the second jar had to wait for the first one to terminate.

Comment: Why can't you start a new process using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()`? and the exit the original program?

Comment: @Codebender I did not know about these options, I will give them a try.